# C# dataset adapting two tables' key together

Tags: c#, dataset

I started using dataset. I load data from XML file.

I have 1 table *GoodGuys*
Looks like:

1. GoodGuyId (int, auto_increment =true)
2. GoodGuyName(string)
3. GoodGuyPicture(string)

I have 2nd table *BadGuys*
Looks like:

1. BadGuyId (int, auto_increment =true)
2. BadGuyName(string)
3. BadGuyPicture(string)

The issue, I have to adapt id's together like list below. When new rows added each other, **there will be no same id twice in both tables**.

1. GoodGuyId => **0**, GoodGuyName => ..., GoodGuyPicture => ...
2. GoodGuyId => **1**, GoodGuyName => ..., GoodGuyPicture => ...
3. BadGuyId  => **2**, BadGuyName  => ..., BadGuyPicture => ...
4. GoodGuyId => **3**, GoodGuyName => ..., GoodGuyPicture => ...
5. BadGuyId  => **4**, BadGuyName  => ..., BadGuyPicture => ...

Is there a automatic way to adapt them together ?

Comment: Why not have only one table with GuyId, GuyName, GuyPicture and a field GoodGuy which determines if it is a good guy or bad guy.

Comment: Just wanted to learn if it is possible.